# 'Unable to resolve module' error in React-Native project, using absolute paths

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, absolute-path

So I'm trying to get my project running on the iOS simulator, but whenever I run react-native run-ios I get this error on the simulator:

"Unable to resolve module 'name/env' from 'Users/nwork/Desktop/name/name-app/name/redux/settings/const.js': Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories: /Users/nwork/Desktop/name/name-app/node_modules/name"

I am using absolute paths, and have a package.json file inside the folder from where I want to import, with this code inside:

```
{
  "name": "name"
}
```

So, the path 'name/env' from the directory /Users/nwork/Desktop/name/name-app/name/redux/settings/const.js should work, right? Why am I still getting this error?? And why is the module also being searched for in the node_modules?

the code for the import, from 'const.js' is:

```
import {
    API_URL,
} from 'name/env'
```

The API_URL that is being imported is no longer in use.. should this make any difference? Could this be the cause of this particular error?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.babelrc` file with the following:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-expo"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-react-jsx-source",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Change the `root` above to whatever directory is applicable. All direct sub-directories can be absolute imports.